# No cookies error on Postman when trying to create routing

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am trying to create routing for register and signIn. While trying to goto sign in route it brings me to the register route and also gives an error on postman:-

```
NO cookies yet.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi please post code snippet here not images

Comment: Hey, I think you are using SIgnUp rather than SignIn in the postman.

Comment: https://github.com/jaysalhan/swiggy/issues/1 Zubair here is the full code bro